# how to add PlausibleDatabase.framework to Xcode 4.1

Tags: database, frameworks, xcode4

I've already add PlausibleDatabase.framework to Xcode4.1 by following steps:

1. my project -- build phases
2. Link binary with Libraries
3. click "+"
4. add other
5. choose where the framework is.

And I tried to

```
#import "PlausibleDatabase.h"
```

got error 'PlausibleDatabase.h' file not found

And I checked the loaded framework, the header file is there! Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should import like this:

```
#import "PlausibleDatabase/PlausibleDatabase.h"
```